# Abort all axios pending requests and create new

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, axios

I am using `axios` for API requests, I have a situation where I want to abort all running/pending requests and create new with another API.

Have tried below code

```
async getOldResponse() {
    const response_old: any = await this.axios.post("/search_old", this.searchData);
    console.log(response_old)
}
async getOldOtherResponse() {
    const response_old_second: any = await this.axios.post("/search_old_second", this.searchData);
    console.log(response_old_second);
}
async getNewSearch() {
    // here i want to cancel all pending requests.
    const CancelToken = this.axios.CancelToken;
    const source = CancelToken.source();
    source.cancel('All previous pending request cancelled');
    const response: any = await this.axios.post("/search_new", this.searchData);
    console.log(response);
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.getOldResponse();
    this.getOldOtherResponse();
    this.getNewSearch();
}
```

Basically I want to abort `/search_old` & `search_old_second` API requests and create `search_new`.

Comment: Did you find your answer? I'm having a similar situation

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cancellation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation)

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();

axios.get('/user/12345', {
  cancelToken: source.token
}).catch(function (thrown) {
  if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
    console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
  } else {
    // handle error
  }
});

axios.post('/user/12345', {
  name: 'new name'
}, {
  cancelToken: source.token
})

// cancel the request (the message parameter is optional)
source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
```

Comment: This code won't help because my previous requests can be from other methods too which i don't want to abort. Just to explain my problem statement i have added it into the same method.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this, but from what i remember it would be something like this.

Taken from axios documentation https://github.com/axios/axios

```
/* create cancel token */
const CancelToken = this.axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();

/* fire requests whose only purpose is to be canceled */
const response_old: any = await this.axios({
  method: 'post',
  cancelToken: source.token,
  url: '/search_old',
  data: this.searchData
})
const response_old_second: any = await this.axios({
  method: 'post',
  cancelToken: source.token,
  url: '/search_old_second',
  data: this.searchData
})

/* cancel all previous pending requests */
source.cancel('optional message')

/* fire new request */
const response: any = await this.axios.post("/search_new", this.searchData);
```